# joomla pretty link

Tags: joomla, friendly-url

how set pretty links in joomla ? (similar to wordpress pretty links)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Joomla root folder and rename htaccess.txt to .htaccess, then go to the administration panel->site->Global Configuration

Set

Search Engine Friendly URLs=> yes

Use Apache mod_rewrite  => yes

If you have any troubles with the new links check the .htaccess file and set the RewriteBase.

Comment: remember, in apache site file : AllowOverride None > AllowOverride all

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that mod_rewrite is enabled, then turn on the "Search Engine Friendly URLs" option in Joomla's Global Configuration settings.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware though that this solution will not provide you with the tracking or analytics the other plugin will.

You also will not be able to put external links in (eg. affiliates) and make them look like you, ex: yourdomain.com/prettyaffiliatelink

Comment: Hello! Welcome to StackOverflow. Thank you for your contribution to this question. I'd like to recommend that if you have a clarification or addition to another solution, that you post it as a comment to that question instead of making a new answer. It helps people reading the question later to get all of the information they need, and also links your addition to that answer to avoid clarification.